# Polarity of gas discharge tubes

Tags: surge-protection, gdt

Do gas discharge tubes used e.g. for surge protection have a polarity, i.e., do they protect in both directions (i.e., depending which wire is hit, or if it is a positive/negative lightnings?

The symbol (see below, [from Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gasableiter)) has a dot that suggests some asymmetry. Electrons should be able to jump in any direction, but how are the positive/negative electrodes engineered to facilitate/stand the discharges?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Photo attribution:
By Ceinturion 17:47, 19 August 2007 (UTC) - Own work, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=2587926[image: By Ceinturion 17:47, 19 August 2007 (UTC) - Own work, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=2587926]

 Small dot indicates "gas-filled". Likely at sub-atmosphere pressure. Its position within the schematic symbol doesn't suggest polarity.
These devices may include thoriated electrodes to reduce striking voltage.
So for this example: it is bipolar....strikes with **either polarity**.

Answer (score 5):

Surge arrestor bulbs for lightning protection are symetrical usually. There are ones with three electrodes but in those, the third electrode is a shared ground, not an ignition electrode as in your examples. The schematic symbol is different then. See e.g. the [this TDK/Epcos datasheet](https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/download/174150/4b2e00d042fd7d7953e0f2c8e60379af/smd-surge-arresters-pb.pdf) (last page).

In contrary, gas bulbs used for lighting purposes are sometimes symetrical, sometimes unsymetrical. See e.g. [this Osram datasheet](https://www.osram.de/appsj/pdc/pdf.do?cid=GPS01_1028555&vid=PP_EUROPE_DE_eCat&lid=DE&mpid=ZMP_56327). Such bulbs may have an additional ignition electrode, which is the third electrode in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Both symmetrical and asymmetrical GDTs exist, the former have a symmetrical symbol, such as those [surge protectors](https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/gas_discharge_tubes/littelfuse_gdt_cg5_sl0902a_datasheet.pdf.pdf) from Littlefuse:

[image]

Comment: Would this imply that the symbols (with a dot not in the middle) in the original question refer to asymmetric GTD? Which electrode is it that is closest to the dot? then?