# What does this symbol mean in the internal circuitry of a surge protector device?

Tags: identification, symbol, surge-protection

[image]

Can't find anything on what the symbol inside of the red circle. Any identification of the symbol would be appreciated, bonus love for its functionality in this circuit as well!

[Link to the datasheet.](https://www.littelfuse.com/media?resourcetype=datasheets&itemid=395c3398-b128-403f-858d-4e1aa4a4aa82&filename=spd2-1-1-datasheet)

Comment: The Q&A [Polarity of gas discharge tubes](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/455664/36731) has some information you might find interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *What does this symbol mean in the internal circuitry of a surge
> protector device?*

It's a spark-gap or gas discharge tube (GDT): -

[image]

Image from [here](https://5.imimg.com/data5/UX/RG/MY-21614932/gas-discharge-tube-28gdt-29-500x500.jpeg)

> *bonus love for its functionality in this circuit as well*

If the voltage gets too high the GDT "fires" and clamps the applied voltage to a a few volts. It's not particularly fast in operation but, it can handle power surges that MOVs or semiconductor clampers can't. However, it's not so useful on a DC supply because once it activates, it will clamp the voltage ad infinitum whereas on AC, its cyclical nature means it can self-reset every half cycle.

Answer (score 7):

Gas discharge tube.  Very high current handling capability, but generally less precise breakdown voltage than semiconductor devices.  Frequently used in conjunction with semiconductor devices to provide lightning strike protection.